# WebGL ThreeJs Skeletal Animation on Windows Issue

Tags: animation, three.js, cross-platform, webgl, skeletal-mesh

I am using **three.js (version 61)** with the WebGL renderer in a project to have a live animation with data detected by the Kinect.

I have used the **THREE.SkinnedMesh** Object to have a 3D model that supports the skeletal animation.

I tested the live skeletal animation in these scenario:

- Test 1 on Windows 7
- Test 2 on Mac OS X 10.9

... and I have this result:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6yEkHWd_4nEVkJ4RzZuMENmZUE/edit?pli=1

**On Windows, the problem is that the final position of some vertex is not well computed!**

I used these browsers:

- Google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63
- Firefox 26.0.

... and the result is the same.

**Is the problem dealing with different GPU drivers and WebGL?**

I haven't a good knowledge in this topic.

**Has anyone encountered and solved a similar problem when performing an animation using a THREE.SkinnedMesh Object on Windows system?**

**Note** 
for the test scenario

- I have a mock of the Kinect: Web App receives data from a server running locally.
- I have exported the rigged model from Blender to three.js and all parameters for the skinned mesh are well exported (as shown in the 2nd test).

Comment: yes, you are right. My comment is not a real explanation, but it has been useful enough for my issue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this answer is not a complete explanation about the problem that I encountered, a solution has been to reuse the automatic skinning tool in Blender to re-assign some vertex to bones.
In this way, exported weights have been also modified and undesired artifacts disappeared.